# WCF Data Service deployment issues AZURE

Tags: c#, azure, entity-framework-5, wcf-data-services

Simular issue:
[WCF Data Service deployment issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568023/wcf-data-service-deployment-issues)

> The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception
>   message is 'The type initializer for
>   'System.Data.Services.Providers.ResourceType' threw an exception.'.
>   See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is:
>
> at
>   System.Data.Services.Providers.ResourceType.get_PrimitiveResourceTypeMap()
>   at
>   System.Data.Services.Providers.ObjectContextServiceProvider.PopulateMetadata(IDictionary`2
>   knownTypes, IDictionary`2 childTypes, IDictionary`2 entitySets) at
>   System.Data.Services.Providers.BaseServiceProvider.LoadMetadata() at
>   System.Data.Services.DataService`1.CreateMetadataAndQueryProviders(IDataServiceMetadataProvider&
>   metadataProviderInstance, IDataServiceQueryProvider&
>   queryProviderInstance, BaseServiceProvider& builtInProvider, Object&
>   dataSourceInstance) at
>   System.Data.Services.DataService`1.CreateProvider() at
>   System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandleRequest() at
>   System.Data.Services.DataService`1.ProcessRequestForMessage(Stream
>   messageBody) at SyncInvokeProcessRequestForMessage(Object , Object[] ,
>   Object[] ) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object
>   instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean
>   isOperationContextSet)

**We are using the follow ddl**
Microsoft.Data.Edm.dll 5.2.0.51212
Microsoft.Data.OData.dll 5.2.0.51212
System.Spatial.dll 5.2.0.51212

We have checked the files on the server, there all there.
The versions are the same

Still have no clue what it could be... Idea's?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved...

First install:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Data.Services -Version 5.2.0
```

In your web.config add:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.Services" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.2.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

And last, Remove all unnessary information in your connecting from metadata so you will end up like this:

```
<add name="MobileDataPlatformEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/; etc...
```

Comment: Any ideas as to why you got this error in the first place?

Comment: version difference somehow, only not sure where exactly.. (sorry)